Not using transaction in pgx causing delays
I'm looking at a web-server that uses golang and pgx v5 for handling interaction with a PostgreSQL 13 database.
These are set-up with gorilla/mux/otelmux and exaring/otelpgx middleware for tracing. otelmux should create a trace for each request and otelpgx should add a span for each database query, for which the request context is used, on the request root span.
The important detail: in a sort of optimization attempt, there is some custom logic that fakes creating a transaction for each request and only begins a real transaction vs. the database when a writing operation is performed. The database transaction isolation level being "read committed", so it doesn't impact integrity. This was allegedly done to reduce the length of transactions.
However, when I look at the traces when the server is under heavy load, I observe that long running requests have significant gaps between any database query spans which are executed before the actual transaction is started (with begin; statement). There are about 15 database queries on average before the first writing query which triggers the begin; query and starts a real transaction. If I modify the code to start a transaction immidiately on receiving the request - these gaps mostly disappear.
My question: could the fact that there is no actual transaction cause a degradation in performance? If so, why does this happen?
My current suspicion is that on some level pgx retains the connection whenever a transaction is using that connection. When there's no transaction every request has to contend in order to get that connection, whereas if there is a long running transaction for that connection, there is no contention (except for the intial begin; statement).
